# node.js Google Sheets API not allowing posting new values

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I've been working on a node.js project that extracts the location of a cell based on a person's name and the date. I can figure that out fairly easily, but when it comes time to post into the cell, the .update function only returns a 400 response, saying that the request is in the wrong form. I've been searching through the documentation for the desired form and have tried playing around with the API console on their website to no avail. Here's a sample of my code

```
active = [<name>, <value>, <comment>, <var>, <column>, <row>];
var request1 = {
        spreadsheetId: <id> ,
        range: active[5] + active[4],
        auth: auth,
        valueInputOption: "RAW",
        resource: {
            "range": active[5] + active[4],
            "values": [active[1]]
        }
    }
sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(request1, function(err, response){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else return;
```

However, this returns the following response,

```
{ message: 'Invalid value at \'data.values[0]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), " "',
   domain: 'global',
   reason: 'badRequest' }
```

I've had no luck figuring out what part of this request makes it 'bad'. The API does not give any clues as to why it won't accept my request. I have the proper scopes and authentication, and my get requests work just fine. The URL in the message links to a 404 page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`values` of the request body using at `sheets.spreadsheets.values.update` is required to be 2 dimensional array. From your question, it seems that `active[1]` is a string. So how about modifying as follows?

#### From :

```
"values": [active[1]]
```

#### To :

```
"values": [[active[1]]]
```

#### Reference :

- [Resource: ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange)

#### Note :

- This answer supposes that you can use Sheets API.
- If this didn't work, can I ask you about the value of `range: active[5] + active[4],`?

Comment: @dropTableUsers Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.